# Why is it printing out more than one time?

Tags: c++

In my text file which it reads is hello world. I need this file to convert the text to binary hexadecimal, cipher, rotation.

When I do `./main -b txt.txt` it prints out several more times than needed. It does the same for hexadecimal output.

The haxe decimal output for hello world will output

> 48656c6c6f20576f726c640a6c6c6f20576f726c640a6c6c6f20576f726cz1882855 
>   binary output is:1001000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100                                   1100100 1010 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100   1                                100100 1010 1101100 1101100 1101111 100000 1010111 1101111 1110010 1101100

The Ceaser cipher also does not work if I do 1 Ceaser cipher it prints out:

> IfmmpUXpseYmmpUXpseYmmpUXps

for hello world

What can I do to fix this problem os it doesn't print out more times than needed.

```
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <getopt.h>
 #include <string>
 #include "more.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
int op = 0;
int opt;
int fd = 1;
int buff = 10;
char buffer[buff];
string s;
int n = 0;
int bytesread= 10;
int i = 2;
ssize_t nr = 0;
string v;
while((op = getopt(argc, argv, "xbs:n:c:r:")) != -1){
    switch(op)
    {
    case 's':
    buff = atoi(optarg);
    i += 2;
    break;
    case 'n':
    bytesread = atoi(optarg);
    n =1;
    i += 2;
    break;
    case 'c':
    i++;
        v = argv[i];
    fd = open(v.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    if (n == 1){
        nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
        if (nr == -1){
            perror("reading file");
            exit(1);
        }
        opt = atoi(optarg);
        s = cipher(buffer,opt,buff);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());

    }
    else{
    do {
    nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
    if (nr == -1){
        perror("reading file");
        exit(1);
    }
    opt = atoi(optarg);
    s  = cipher(buffer,opt,buff);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }while(nr != 0);
    }
    break;
    case 'r':
    i++;
    v = argv[i];
    fd = open(v.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    if (n == 1){
    nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
    opt = atoi(optarg);
    s = rotation(buffer,opt);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }
    else{
    do{
    nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
    if (nr == -1){
        perror("reading file");
        exit(1);
    }
    opt = atoi(optarg);
    s  = rotation(buffer,opt);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }while(nr != 0);
    }
    break;
    case 'x':
        v = argv[i];
    fd = open(v.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    if (n == 1){
        nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
        s = hexa(buffer,buff);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }
    else{
    do {
    nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
    if (nr == -1){
        perror("reading file");
        exit(1);
    }
    s  = hexa(buffer,buff);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }while(nr != 0);
    }
    break;
    case 'b':
    v = argv[i];
    fd = open(v.c_str(),O_RDONLY);
    if (n == 1){
    nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
    if (nr == -1){
        perror("reading file");
        exit(1);
    }
    s  = binary(buffer);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }
    else{
    do{
        nr = read(fd,buffer,bytesread);
        if (nr == -1){
        perror("reading file");
        exit(1);
        }
    s  = binary(buffer);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,s.c_str(),s.size());
    }while(nr != 0);
    }
    break;
    default:
        int  buf[10];
    fd = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1){
        perror("opening file");
        exit(1);
        }
    do {
    nr = read(fd,buf,bytesread);
    if (nr == -1){
        perror("reading file");
        exit(1);                            
    }
    write(1,buf,nr);
    }while(nr != 0);
    close(fd);
    break;      
    }   

}

return 0;
}

 #include <iostream>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <bits/stdc++.h> 
 #include "more.h"

using namespace std;

constexpr char hexmap[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                           '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

string cipher(char buffer[],int opt,int size){
string s = "";
for (int i = 0;i < size-1;i++){
    if (isupper(buffer[i]))
        s += char(int(buffer[i]+opt-65)%26+65);
    else 
        s += char(int(buffer[i]+opt-97)%26+97);
    }

  return s;

}
string rotation(char buffer[], int opt){
string s = buffer;
reverse(s.begin(), s.begin()+opt); 
    reverse(s.begin()+opt, s.end()); 
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());    
return s;
}

string hexa(char buffer[],int size){
string str;
string n = buffer;
int s = n.size();
for( int i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
    char const byte = buffer[i];
    str  += hexmap[ ( byte & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ];
    str  += hexmap[ ( byte & 0x0F ) >> 0 ];
}

return str;
}

string binary(char buffer[]){
string n = buffer;
int s = n.size();
string t = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= s+1; i++)  { 
     int val = int(n[i]); 
     string bin = ""; 
     while (val > 0){
        (val % 2)? bin.push_back('1'):
            bin.push_back('0');
        val /= 2;
     }
     reverse(bin.begin(),bin.end());
         t += bin + " " ;
    }
   return t;              

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: You're using the C++ language but also using a lot of C-isms. You'd be better off doing things the C++ way in C++.